# Bitmap "OutOfMemoryError" in Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I've referred more about my issue. But i couldn't able to solve my issue yet and i can't able to predict why it is happening on particular device especially Galaxy S3. I also run the same App in other devices, it's working fine. I found a memory leak using eclipse MAT. It's exactly on my image editing class which is used on my App. I've not tried bitmap.recyle(), because i used this through out the application. ImageEditView class is for displaying the image on screen. I've loaded bitmap by using below snippet.

```
private Bitmap decodeAndDownsampleImageURI(Uri uri) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    try {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        options.inPurgeable = true; 

        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
        in.close();

        int scale = 1;
        if (options.outHeight > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE || options.outWidth > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
            scale = (int) Math.pow(
                    2,
                    (int) Math.round(Math.log(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE / (double) Math.max(options.outHeight, options.outWidth))
                                        / Math.log(0.5)));
        }

        options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = scale;
        in = new BufferedInputStream(getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
        in.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        log.error(MyStyleApplication.hockeyAppLogMessage, e);
        Log.e(TAG, "decodeAndDownsampleImageUri()", e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(MyStyleApplication.hockeyAppLogMessage, e);
        Log.e(TAG, "decodeAndDownsampleImageUri()", e);
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

}

Anyone please suggest me a better solutions to come out my issue.

Comment: You need to clear bitmap cache and use LRU cache. As an alternative you can use UniversalImageLoader. Good luck

Comment: Experts please refer follow report  and suggest me a better solution. One instance of "com.newvisioninteractive.android.mystyle.widget.ImageEditView" loaded by "dalvik.system.PathClassLoader @ 0x41be12d0" occupies 50,538,632 (73.52%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "com.newvisioninteractive.android.mystyle.widget.ImageEditView" loaded by "dalvik.system.PathClassLoader @ 0x41be12d0".

Keywords
dalvik.system.PathClassLoader @ 0x41be12d0
com.newvisioninteractive.android.mystyle.widget.ImageEditView

Comment: @Yume117 Thanks for your suggestion. I've been trying your method. If you paste some examples , that would be easy for me to implement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code. It will solve your problems

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                                options.inSampleSize = 4;
 in = new BufferedInputStream(getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
```

If you are still proble then you can downscale your image.

```
Bitmap newBmp=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap , 100, 100, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When i used your snippet, my app feel the difference. But it still keep on increase the heap size and when i load this class it occupy 40% memory. It's really too bad right. I can't able to free up the space. Do you have any solutions? In addition i used seekbar to erase the background, if seekbar size increased heap size getting increased. I've only 2% of free space when i loading this class. Any suggestions?.

Comment: If i increased the options.inSampleSize , the selected images are not properly adapt to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can't save all bitmap in memory, which will run out of memory. You have to write data to disk cache. The memory data is only needed for current screen, or switching screen, like flicking image to left or right in Gallery. Your app must be driven by some events. so there is enough time to decode bitmap data again from your cache when some events triggered.